# Ending of the story Mirror of Ice

Tags: short-stories

In this story, there's a dispute about the ending. Is this is an open ending, or does it end with the protagonist winning the race?

Story (rough edit) is here: https://groups.google.com/g/rec.arts.sf.written/c/tF2gWUrE_fY

Comment: What about this story of downhill bobsledding is scifi or fantasy?

Comment: @Valorum The story is "Mirror of Ice" by Gary Wright ([*Galaxy*, June 1967](http://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?52389)), and is on-topic.  ([Previous question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/242678/101407)) I don't know about *this* question, though.

Comment: @SaraPhina _Where_ is there a dispute about the ending?  It's pretty clear that the protagonist lost control on the Plummet - he directly says that.  He crashes and wakes up in the hospital; he obviously didn't win.

Answer (score 1):

As DavidW indicates, the story ends with the protagonist in the hospital, having crashed and lost. The only uncertainty is whether he'll race again, and based on his mindset, I suspect that's only a matter of whether he can make himself physically able to get back into the sled.

> The hospital. How many times had he awakened here?
> And it was always wonderfully the same: gentle warmth and
> his body finally relaxed and he would test it piece by piece to
> see what was bent and broken this time; and always the
> newsmen and the writers and the other assorted ghouls, and
> always the question and answer period. Punchlining, they
> called it. . . .
> "How did it happen?"
> "I dozed off."
> "Why didn't you eject?"
> "Parachuting is dangerous."
> "When did you realize you were out of control?"
> "At the starting line."
> "What will you do now?"
> "Heal."
> "Will you race again?"
> . . . "It's possible."
> Outside, the wind was blowing.

To me the story is complete. Whether or not the narrator recovers, he will face The Stuka over and over again, knowing there's almost no chance of winning, but driven to face death once more and hope to triumph.